# multiprocessing add arguments later on

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I want to determine my multiprocess and later on my arg for the multiprocess.

So I could run this process to say something and when it must say something else that it can change easily.

```py
import multiprocessing

def tts(Say):
    print(Say)

say = ""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    core1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=tts, args=(say,))
    say = "Hello"
    core1.start()
    core1.join()
```

Now it prints nothing and I want it to print Hello.

Comment: Please edit your code to include the line that fails `core2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=tts(Say=say))`

Comment: Using a debugger would help you visualize what's going wrong here. You'll see that `Say` doesn't have a value when you reference it on line 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the process class:

```
class Proc(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, ss, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Proc, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ss = ss

    def run(self):
        print(self.ss)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pp = Proc('aaa')
    pp.ss = 'bbb'
    pp.start()
    pp.join()
```

This will print `bbb`

Comment: Thanks it works fine but why is there the 'aaa' in ```Proc('aaa') ```

Comment: As an example, to hold the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing tts an object which has not been defined. As python is interpreted, it checks for value of `Say` when you call `core1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=tts(Say))`

```
Say = "Hello"
core1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=tts(Say))
core1.start()
```

Comment: Sorry but I meant define Say after you defined core1.

Comment: I've edited my code above so it's more clearly. What I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for a way to update the variable.

```py
import multiprocessing
def tts(Say):
    print(Say)

say = ""
def core1(action):
    exec("multiprocessing.Process(target=tts, args=(say,))"+action)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    say = "Hello"
    core1(".start()")
```

Is there a better way to get this?